# Java NetBeans GUI Key Event sending

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm making a simple calculator, so far I did a text field where I can type numbers and it listens if key was typed from keyboard.

```
private void resultKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {  }
```

What I want is to click on let's say '1' with mouse and send a key event to this method, so it would be like I clicked it on keyboard. Tried doing keypress with robot but it says 'void type is no good here' or something like that. I wanted to just run that resultKeyTyped method from withing mouse click listener, like this:

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) 
{
    resultKeyTyped(KeyEvent.VK_1);
}
```

Comment: `it listens if key was typed from keyboard` Why do you need to listen for key events? If you want to listen to when the JTextField text changes, consider using a [DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

Comment: You just did basically what I said, only difference is that you are using a mouselistener. You should just make a button/jbutton and add an ACTIONlistener.

Comment: @copeg, he is getting keyboard input, but he also wants buttons that can be clicked, just like the windows calculator

Comment: @ Mrab Ezreb, a JTextField already handles keyboard input without the need for a KeyListener - hence my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call the `resultKeyTyped`, you have to pass a [KeyEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html). You can just create a KeyEvent using appropriate constructor:

```
KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(textField, 0, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, KeyEvent.VK_1);
resultKeyTypes(event);
```

Although from your description (eg `simple calculator`), it sounds like you may wish to choose a different approach:

1. Add an `ActionListener` to the `JButton`
2. Within the implementation of the `ActionListener`, change the `JTextField` text by using the `setText` method

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this (assuming that you are clicking on a Button instead of something else) in my opinion would be this:

```
Button button1 = new Button("1");
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    int thisKey = KeyEvent.VK_1;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        resultKeyTyped(thisKey);
    }
});
```

Now, the one thing that you need to change is that resultKeyTyped needs to take an int as a parameter instead of a keyevent. From what I understand, all that you care about is which key was pressed, not how long it was pressed or anything like that. So, wherever you call resultKeyTyped, pass it KeyEvent.getKey()

Hopefully this helped!

P.S. if you really want a keyevent, you can use the keyevent constructor,  but since you were using a robot anyways, I am pretty sure that you only care about the key